# Difference between dates returns weird results

Tags: java

I'm calculating the difference in minutes between two date-time in that way:

```
long diff = time2.getTime() - time1.getTime();

return diff / (60 * 1000);
```

For a strange reason it returns a lower number of minutes than expected.

For example the difference between `2014-01-22 18:45:00` and `2014-01-22 18:03:00` is `41 minutes` when it should be `42 minutes`

What's the reason? How to fix it?

EDIT

The debugger show "2014-01-22 18:45:00.0" for date1 and "Wed Jan 22 18:03:31 GMT 2014" for date2. I don't know why it's showing different syntaxes.

Comment: What are the exact values of `time1` and `time2`?

Comment: Probably rounding - fractions of seconds that are truncated.

Comment: Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Have you got some code that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Running your code, I get 42.

Comment: @ZouZou, well, that's just the answer to everything!  :-)

Comment: @DavidWallace Just to say that this snippet of code is not enough to answer the question :-)

Comment: Are you sure that the date objects have the milliseconds set to zero? if the earlier time is `2014-02-22 18:03:00.001', and the later one is `2014-01-22 18:45:00.000`, you will get 41 minutes because division with longs truncates the remainder, not rounding.

Comment: If `date1` is 18:45:00 and `date2` is 18:03:31, as per your edit, then the difference is 41 minutes and 29 seconds, not 42 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to divide by `60f * 1000`, you will see a result of 41.something because `getTime()` takes into consideration the milliseconds as well, and as you can see these are not zeros in your date values.

Answer (score 1):

Its rounding problem. Long truncates the decimal, you should use Double in this case if u want the exact number.

Answer (score 0):

Like Oracle explains...

```
public long getTime()
```

*Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date*

It's a rounding problem. If you round the two 'times' (both upper or lower) you won't have any problem, but if not both will take in account the ms and your result can vary 1 minute (your minimum grain of detail). I would use the class `double` instead of long as [@Nguyten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2341121/nguyen-le) Le has said.